# Mongo query to convert Int/double to string with comma separated values and appended $ sign

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am looking for an aggregate mongo query where my output should be in **"$236,535.73"** format.
Can anyone please suggest/help with the query?

I am trying to use the below query but it is truncating my decimal values:
 "totalDue" : { $concat: [ " $", {"$toString" : "$totalDue.value"} ] }

Below is my mongoDB structure
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfLK0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no operator for converting a `Double` to a comma-seperated formatted `String` (as of MongoDB 4.2). It will a be complex query and potentially slow on large dataset.

It would be better to just handle this at your application layer.
Since you have tagged the question with `javascript`, there is [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })
console.log(formatter.format(236535.73))
// output: "$236,535.73"
```